# How to loop in visual basic?

Tags: visual-studio

So i have an assignment and im struggling to add a loop.
I want to make 3  valid answers for the question and any other inputs would cause the code to say invalid vehicle type and ask the questions again.

I tried doing it for a few days but i cant make the loops as it just ends when i run the code or goes to the next question even if the answers invalid

The programs 2019 visual basic
Code:

```
Dim vehicle_type As string
Dim days_required as integer
Dim insurance_cover as string
Dim new_existing as string
Dim B_S_G As string
Dim total_hire_cost as single
Const lowemission as single =15.5
Const zero emission as single =20.0
Const electric as single 32.0

Vehicle_type = inputbox("enter any 3 vehicle types, lowemission, zeroemission or electric")

Do
  Msgbox("invalid vehicle type")
Loop until vehicle type <> lowemission or zeroemission or electric
```

Comment: So you've posted the code you're now using. Great! What kind of app is this? Console? WinForms? What is the code not doing that you want it to. Be specific, like, "I typed xxx into the inputbox but it didn't drop out of the loop". How are you testing this?

Comment: Im using visual basic, window forms app (.NET FRAMEWORK). so i want the code to ask the user which vehicle type they want. If the user puts a different input other than the 3 vehicle types than i want it to say invalid vehichle type and then loop back and ask the question again sk the user can input there answer again

Comment: WinForms. Nice. So is this code in a Button Click event maybe? What is triggering it? I've personally tested both my approach and the code posted by Enigmativity. They both work as you've described. Thus, if you want help getting it to work we need to figure out what is DIFFERENT about your setup. The only way to do that is to see more code and/or get more details about your specific problem. We can't see your screen and see what is happening when you interact with your application. Help us to help you.

Comment: @Codingnoob - Please don't steal the code in my answer and replace your code with it. If you want to follow on from my answer then edit your question and put my code at the end, explaining where you got it from, and what further help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
Do
    vehicle_type = InputBox("enter any 3 vehicle types, lowemission, zeroemission or electric")
    If vehicle_type = "lowemission" Or vehicle_type = "zeroemission" Or vehicle_type = "electric" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    MsgBox("invalid vehicle type")
Loop
```

Comment: Hi, i tried it and it didnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an array to hold your valid responses:

```
Dim index As Integer
Dim types() As String = {"lowemission", "zeroemission", "electric"}
Dim strTypes As String = String.Join(", ", types)
Do
    vehicle_type = InputBox("Valid Vehicle types:" & vbCrLf & strTypes, "Enter vehicle type").ToLower().Trim()
    index = Array.IndexOf(types, vehicle_type)
    If index = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("invalid vehicle type")
    End If
Loop While index = -1
```

Looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hi, this may work but its got things like index and arrays stuff which we werent taught.

Comment: Also the code doesnt work, it loops but when i type in any of the vehicle types.nothing happens

Comment: I assure you it does work. If you'd like help implementing this type of approach in your project then we'd need to see your attempt at implementing it. If you can't use Arrays then a compound boolean statement like in Enigmativity's post would be your best bet.

Comment: Yh sorry ive tried it and it doesnt seem to work, im on 2019 visual basic btw so i might be on a newer version

Comment: Nothing to do with versions. I tested the code before I posted and it works. If "it doesn't work" then either (1) You've implemented it wrong, or (2) You haven't explained the details of your question well enough for us to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thats very strange, i have no idea then

Comment: Like I said, we can help you implement the various approaches we've presented, but YOU have to update your post with your attempt so we can see what you did.  =)

Comment: Co ill update the code in my post